# Feature Vectors in Radial Basis Function Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, point-clouds

I am trying to use RBFNN for point cloud to surface reconstruction but I couldn't understand what would be my feature vectors in RBFNN.

Can any one please help me to understand this one.

**A goal to get to this:**
[image: http://www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr/site/sites/default/files/resize/bunny5-200x200.jpg]

**From inputs like this:**
[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of the data you're starting with?

Comment: @ohruunuruus, yes, i have point cloud data which just contains (x,y,z) coordinates, e.g. (1,2.44,2.5), (2,4.55, 2.555) .... 
some thing like this .. 
http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~zwood/teaching/csc570/final13/jdforres/images/slider/bunny-final2.png
and i want to make the surface out of it like this 
http://www.creatis.insa-lyon.fr/site/sites/default/files/resize/bunny5-200x200.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An RBF network essentially involves fitting data with a linear combination of functions that obey a set of core properties -- chief among these is radial symmetry. The parameters of each of these functions is learned by incremental adjustment based on errors generated through repeated presentation of inputs.

If I understand (it's been a very long time since I used one of these networks), your question pertains to preprocessing of the data in the point cloud. I believe that each of the points in your point cloud should serve as one input. If I understand properly, *the features are your three dimensions, and as such each point can already be considered a "feature vector."*

You have other choices that remain, namely the number of radial basis neurons in your hidden layer, and the radial basis functions to use (a Gaussian is a popular first choice). The training of the network and the surface reconstruction can be done in a number of ways but I believe this is beyond the scope of the question.

I don't know if it will help, but here's a simple python implementation of an RBF network performing function approximation, with one-dimensional inputs:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fit_me(x):
    return (x-2) * (2*x+1) / (1+x**2)

def rbf(x, mu, sigma=1.5):
    return np.exp( -(x-mu)**2 / (2*sigma**2));

# Core parameters including number of training
# and testing points, minimum and maximum x values
# for training and testing points, and the number
# of rbf (hidden) nodes to use
num_points = 100    # number of inputs (each 1D)
num_rbfs = 20.0     # number of centers
x_min = -5
x_max = 10

# Training data, evenly spaced points
x_train = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, num_points)
y_train = fit_me(x_train)

# Testing data, more evenly spaced points
x_test  = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, num_points*3)
y_test  = fit_me(x_test)

# Centers of each of the rbf nodes
centers = np.linspace(-5, 10, num_rbfs)

# Everything is in place to train the network
# and attempt to approximate the function 'fit_me'.

# Start by creating a matrix G in which each row
# corresponds to an x value within the domain and each 
# column i contains the values of rbf_i(x).
center_cols, x_rows = np.meshgrid(centers, x_train)
G = rbf(center_cols, x_rows)

plt.plot(G)
plt.title('Radial Basis Functions')
plt.show()

# Simple training in this case: use pseudoinverse to get weights
weights = np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(G), y_train)

# To test, create meshgrid for test points
center_cols, x_rows = np.meshgrid(centers, x_test)
G_test = rbf(center_cols, x_rows)

# apply weights to G_test
y_predict = np.dot(G_test, weights)

plt.plot(y_predict)
plt.title('Predicted function')
plt.show()

error = y_predict - y_test

plt.plot(error)
plt.title('Function approximation error')
plt.show()
```

First, you can explore the way in which inputs are provided to the network and how the RBF nodes are used. This should extend to 2D inputs in a straightforward way, though training may get a bit more involved.

To do proper surface reconstruction you'll likely need a representation of the surface that is altogether different than the representation of the function that's learned here. Not sure how to take this last step.

Comment: so, is that means each of the point in point cloud is the feature vector/ input vector in RBF and as you mentioned "fitting data", is it actually trying to fit a surface to these point? sorry but I'm really new in this area

Comment: @jquery404 It might be best to start with a simpler example (e.g. 2D points, which will make visualizing easier) and focus on function approximation. Hopefully this will provide a basic understanding that you can extend to surface reconstruction.

Comment: @jquery404 I added an example of an RBF network performing function approximation. Maybe this will help get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much. I explored 1D and 2D function approximation techniques as u suggested before, and understood how this work and after that I found your example it helped me more ...but still have confusion on surface reconstruction. and i got this post where they mentioned:
The surface-reconstruction method using RBF consists of two steps: (i) computing an interpolating implicit function the zero set of
which contains the points in the data set, followed by 
(ii) extraction of isocurves or isosurfaces. 
any idea how to approach this ?